# How do you output the value of a checkbox item?

Tags: templating, field

Seems like it should be simple but it's not working for me.

```
{% for option in entry.contributionType %}
     <li> {{ option.value }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This code outputs the option's label instead of  the value. I feel like I'm going crazy.

Comment: That should work. Have you tried `{{ option.label }}:{{ option.value }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just figured it out. Apparently, when I changed the value of the fields in the settings I had to re-save all entries that used that field. And not just re-save them, but reset the value in the field as well, because it had lost it's checked value when I opened the entry up to edit it.

I see now the warning in the field settings I had previously overlooked, "Changing this may result in data loss."